# Mobile network perfomance: What would be the most efficient data-type to transfer data from a webserver to a mobilephone?

Tags: android, ios, performance, mobile, client-server

**Q:** What kind of data-type would be the most efficient/fastest to use when transfering data between a webserver(/other?) and a mobile phone, ie ios/android/other?

- JSON ?
- XML ?
- HTML ?

**Q:** What kind of serverside technologies should be used?

- php + mysql ?

**Q:** What kind of API should be used?

- Restfull?
- RPC ?

Any thoughs ?

Comment: How large amounts of data are we talking? Efficient with respect to what?

Comment: Iam thinking about speed. When user starts a request till it gets back and then parsed to whatever the user should see. Data amount would be less than a normal webpage since the rendering would be done by the phone (tableviews etc just showing the returned data)

Comment: Hello Rasmus, what is your application going to be doing? I have worked on trading applications which required very high messaging throughput between client / server. The fastest combination was RabbitMQ/Protobuffers which allows cross-platform binary messaging with round trip processing times <1ms

Comment: Hi Andrew, iam programming applications for dictionaries - people login, search a word (in a wordcompletion way; they type and the tablelist is updated for each letter pressed). When user selects a word in the list they are presented with an article that can vary alot on in size. The articles is currently formatted in HTML that is then displayed inside a webview. I want to speed up the whole process from logging in, searching and viewing articles. Login/search and other tasks is responded in XML.

Comment: AutoComplete sounds to me like the bottleneck. Think about how Google responds to autocomplete search requests. They use internally protobuffers for serialization and externally most likely JSON not binary. They use asynchronous web services to provide the data. If you limit your autocomplete results to 10 then you will get a huge performance boost. For instance, user types in "Fa.." they get a list including "Fast", "Fancy", "Fan" etc with a maximum of 10 results returned, not "all matches from dictionary matching Fa". Also they will not return any suggestions until you have at least 2 chars

Comment: Autocomplete over mobile networks could be fun! I'd test a prototype in some real world situations, the latency can be anywhere from 150ms to 500ms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **A1.** Binary.

Have you looked at [Google Protobuffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)? this is an efficient binary formatter with cross-platform capabilities (java, c#, python, objective c, PhP. There's even a JScript implementation knocking about but I wouldnt trust it!)

Have you looked at messaging frameworks such as AMQP? I have successfully implemented a cross-platform binary messaging system using [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/) as a message router, [Protobuffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as binary serializer and [Rabbit MQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) as C# and Java client. It was extraordinarily fast and could perform a roundtrip request/response from client to server and back (including serialization/deserialization, excluding network times) in only 0.5ms.

The messaging stack becomes:

> Mobile > RabbitMQ Client > Google Protobuffers > {the internet} > RabbitMQ Server > Google Protobuffers > Webserver

JSON is your next fastest serializer but nothing can compare to binary for speed and efficient use of bandwidth.

> **A2.** For performance Oracle will handle the most data, SQL Server and MySql will give very good results though depending on what you intend to do.

It also depends on how your data is going to be stored. Are you storing relational data? Then use a relational database. Are you storing time series data? Then use a column-ordered database or even a flat file. PyTables is an excellent example of python-based file centric database which is highly suited to storing scientific datasets and timeseries.

The answer to this question really is "It depends" - on what you want to do. I would also consider developing in a serverside technology you know well rather than pick one based on numbers as they are all fairly similar.

> **A3.** Unknown, not my area of expertise.

Best regards,

Comment: I was reading about google protobuffers/rabbitmq. Looks interresting. I will have a better look at it soon and try it out.

Comment: Yes often overlooked, asynchronous messaging (like AMQP which RabbitMQ is a client/server for) is very lightweight, fast and handles high data. Technologies like this are used in trading applications to achieve low latencies. Combined with binary serialization this can be a formidable solution :)

Comment: Right now we limit each dictionary to return a maximum of 6 results. But some user have up to 50 dictionaries and when they search 'auto' (in all 50 dictionaries/directions) then we get into trouble.

Comment: are you putting all 6*50 results in a dropdown box for autocomplete? Surely this is overkill and you could return the top 10 matches across all 50 dictionaries. Perhaps I dont understand the requirement correctly but I'd be looking to limit data displayed as opposed to tuning performance. You could certainly get a boost by switching to JSON or Binary serialization as mentioned, but the underlying requirement seems to be off as a user can't even view that much data (300 results in autocomplete)

Comment: That is also only very few (and the users can select to search in a range of the dictionaries if he wants to) - when the inputted text is below 3 chars we search for exact matches, meaning a lot of dicts don't return anything. All results is put into a tableview (if your familiar with the one on iOS)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what do you mean by efficient? In regards to mobile network performance, I would assume you are talking about what would be the lowest latency from sending the web-request to receiving the response.

If we are talking small amounts of data (<~100kByte) the format probably would not be that important, the RTT will be much more important than the throughput, thus you can choose freely between JSON, XML, etc.

For larger data amounts the verbosity of the textual formats you mention might become a significant factor, as the throughput will become the bottleneck, and you could consider just gzipping it, e.g. JSON+gzip. That will cause a processing penalty.

You could probably do some testing to see when the benefit of compressing the data outweighs the penalty of the processing required for compression.

Answer (score 1):

**A1**

It's not just about the transfer it's how it's going to be processed on the client side e.g. is it being retrieved using a HTML client?

Latency is a real killer on mobile, but memory is a also big issue - I'd choose the format that is easiest for the client to handle maybe JSON(P) but I'd want to look at the data/application in more detail to make a real recommendation.

If you're writing a native app it's certainly worth considering a binary protocol like ProtoBuffers or Thrift but I'd be tempted to knock up a prototype using JSON or one of the other text formats first.

**A2**

Probably what you know best (within reason)

**A3**

I'd go for REST on the basis that some requests will be GETs.

RPC suggests that the requests will be POSTs and some browsers split AJAX POSTs into two TCP packets, the second of which is only sent when the first is acknowledged (bad in high latency environments).

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Andrew said: "It depends". All depends what kind of application you are developing. Give us more explanation!

Comment: Q2/3 certainly depend on the target application, For Q1 binary followed by JSON are the fastest and most efficient serializers

Comment: @RasmusStyrk Look for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org). Its fast and perfect to autocomplete!