# Protobuffers in Objective C - unable to reference ProtocolBuffers.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm using xcode 4.2 to do an app for iPhone and I need to use protobuf serialization.
How should I do it?
I've tried this [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) but I can't figure out how to make a reference to ProtocolBuffers.h in xcode 4.2.

Comment: that's very kind of you to mark my Q as answer, however did it answer it? If I recall you had trouble referencing ProtoBuffers.h in xcode - have you found out how that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710654/mobile-network-perfomance-what-would-be-the-most-efficient-data-type-to-transfe/8710696#8710696). Protobuffers has an [Objective C implementation](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) so can most likely be used on an iOS client. In order to handle messaging to/from the client & server I can recommend [RabbitMQ.](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) I've not used any of these technologies on iOS but have successfully used them in cross-platform Java/C# apps - and they are very fast indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've tried this [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) but I can't figure out how to make a reference to ProtocolBuffers.h in xcode 4.2.

Comment: Hello there, as I said I'm not familiar with iOS so I can't help in this respect. What I suggest you do is rephrase the question to "Protobuffers in Objective C - unable to reference ProtocolBuffers.h" and add that detail to your question text. This will help people know what you've tried and will result in more accurate answers. Hope that helps!